# How to display a layer in front of a loading class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now, I have found the following piece of code online, and I need to modify it so that I can display a div layer in front of the grey loading overlay.

Will a body onload function work to make a div layer visible in this case?  You can see this piece of code in action here:
https://jsfiddle.net/t9tmzws4/

```css
html {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

html.loading {
  background: #333 url('http://www.airfares.ga/icons/238.gif') no-repeat 50% 200px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0;
  transition: background-color 0;
}

body {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

html.loading body {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0;
  transition: opacity 0;
}

button {
  background: #00A3FF;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<html class="loading">
<head>
  <script>
    var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    var removeLoading = function() {
      // In a production application you would remove the loading class when your
      // application is initialized and ready to go.  Here we just artificially wait
      // 3 seconds before removing the class.
      setTimeout(function() {
        html.className = html.className.replace(/loading/, '');
      }, 3000);
    };
    removeLoading();
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  sdfsdfsdfsdf
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `can display a div layer in front of the grey loading overlay` still unclear! try to explain more

Comment: okay, when you open up your browser, what do you first see with the above code?  a grey loading layer which disappears and after 3-4 seconds revealing the contents of the page.  So all I want is to display a layer with text and images in front of this grey loading layer.    If you notice the code it is programmed to show a spinner while it loads the main contents. I need a layer instead of a background image.  Clear?

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is it's just add a `class` to `html` tag then remove it when page loaded. you should try another code, if you don't resist to use this code, tell me i will help you to use another.

Comment: I have tried another code, and the problem was it displayed a layer and removed the layer while the contents were not fully loaded.  extending the time the layer displays would reduce the user experience having them wait for too long looking at a loading screen unnecessary.  This code was the closest I got to making the loading screen disappear as soon the content was ready to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The only way is `pseudo element` on `html` tag while it has `loading` class:*

```
html.loading::before {
    content: "Loading...";
    color: #ff5656;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

*If you want, can add another thing like image or etc with `::after` on `html`*

```css
html {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

html.loading::before {
    content: "Loading...";
    color: #ff5656;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

html.loading {
  background: #333 url('http://www.airfares.ga/icons/238.gif') no-repeat 50% 200px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0;
  transition: background-color 0;
}

body {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

html.loading body {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0;
  transition: opacity 0;
}

button {
  background: #00A3FF;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<html class="loading">
<head>
  <script>
    var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    var removeLoading = function() {
      // In a production application you would remove the loading class when your
      // application is initialized and ready to go.  Here we just artificially wait
      // 3 seconds before removing the class.
      setTimeout(function() {
        html.className = html.className.replace(/loading/, '');
      }, 3000);
    };
    removeLoading();
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  sdfsdfsdfsdf
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works perfectly as described in my question.  I was wondering if the content property could accept html tags for example <div> <h1>helloworld</h1></div>  then I could use this to display the images and text I need to display.

Comment: @KubenPadayachee No, it not accept `html` tags, but you can easily use an image. for example `html.loading::after { content: "", width: 200px; height: 200px; background: url('..');display:block}`